# I am getting error " Mismatched [price] (page crawl) " Google merchant centre?

Tags: shopify, google-search-console, google-shopping-api, google-shopping

I am getting Mismatched [price] (page crawl) error in google Merchant centre.

Store is changing Price & Currency based on the Location of the visitors. Like If I visit store from New Zealand it will show Price in NZD but if the same page is visited from the USA then it will show the price in USD.

I have currency converter on website Shopify code that is involved in other things and i don't want to remove it.

Is there anyone know how to  fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have researched a lot and there was schema problem on website and there was currency convertor running automatically on Shopify theme and I have turned that off. That's fixed the issue.